# Why it would cause an infinite loop here

Tags: java, multithreading

Well,I'm reading an article involved in interrupt in java.Now I don't understand a sample very well as shown below:
  [image]

I'm wondering why it will cause an infinite loop there.What does "It can't restore the interrupt status earlier" mean.
  Appreciate any help.Thanks.

Comment: @Gray:I'm sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering why it will cause an infinite loop there.What does "It can't restore the interrupt status earlier" mean.

So typically you restore the interrupt state *immediately* in the `catch` block.  However, if this was done in this case and then it loops around and called `take()` again, it would cause another throw of `InterruptedException` and an infinite loop.

For me, the question with the code is why, if the thread was interrupted, does the code loop around and call `take()` again.  Typically we are in a loop that is something like:

```
 while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
     ...
 }
```

Maybe the author of the code is confusing spurious wakeups with spurious interrupts?  I don't think that the latter actually happen.  Certainly spurious wakeups happen but those are handled internally by the `queue.take()` method.

Typically we restore the thread interrupt status with something like the following code:

```
 try {
    queue.take();
 } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    // because catching InterruptedException clears the thread interrupt bit,
    // we immediately re-interrupt the current thread.
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    // handle the interrupt here by quitting or returning or ...
 }
```

Comment: I guess if it is that once you call Thread.currentThread().interrupt() immediately in the catch clause, that will cause queue.take() throw an InterruptedException again, so there will be an infinite loop.Am I right?

Comment: @tuanlong Yes, it would probably just fast-path out of `take()` and immediately throw the exception.  If you ignore it and don't reset the flag, it will continue over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

An infinite loop can happen here if `take()` throws `InterruptedException` like the site says.

This is because the expression is evaluated before it is returned so if the evaluation of it throws an exception, you instantly jump to the `catch` block, skipping the `return`.

Comment: If `queue` was null, a `NullPointerException` would be thrown, and since it isn't caught it would just bubble up.  I don't think it would loop infinitely in this case.

Comment: I'm so sorry I didn't notice that that picture was too small to be read. I'll pay attention to it next time.Thank you very much.

Comment: easier just to post it as text, then half blind guys like me can change the text size ;)